# How to transfer sqldatareader to textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I can only read from gridview. I want to pass the read file from the textbox upon the user logs in..

Here is my Data Access Tier

```
public static SqlDataReader GetInformation(string Username)
{
    string sql = "Select Idno, Lname, Mname, Username, Password, ConPass, SchoolYear, TermGraduated from Graduates where Username = @username";
    Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
    Close();
    return sdr;    
}
```

And here is my Bussiness Logic Layer

```
public IDataReader GetInformation()
{
    return DAT.GetInformation(this.username);
}
```

Then my presentation layer in form_load

```
b.Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
```

How can I transfer the data from the textboxes? The only thing I can do is to transfer it using a gridview. But how can I all transfer the data from the textboxes like "TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5..." And so on

Comment: "How can I transfer the data from the textbox?" What textbox?

Comment: Updated my question. It should be textboxes. How can i populate the textboxes based on that statement.

Comment: Where are the text-boxes?? Or you just trying to fill a gridview? do you have textboxes in template fields

Comment: @JmSantos even with update I cannot understand: what "textboxes"? And the "from" word sounds strange in this sentence. Could you clarify?

Comment: @JmSantos: And this way of coding, where is the data-reader get closed?

Comment: I just tried to transfer it to a gridview because i can't transfer it through textboxes like Column1 = TextBox1..

Comment: I forgot to put the close.. I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood your question

Create a class to represent data, let say Graduate

```
public class Graduate
{
     public long Id {get;set;}
     public string LastName {get;set;}
     //rest of the fields
}

public static Graduate GetInformation(string Username)
{

//haven't put all the code here, you have the idea I guess
//also wrap this around try-catch block


    string sql = "Select Idno, Lname, Mname, Username, Password, ConPass, SchoolYear,    TermGraduated from Graduates where Username = @username";
    Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

using(var sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
   if(sdr.HasRows)
   {
       while(sdr.Read())
       {
          var objGard = new Graduate()
                     {
                        ID = sdr["Idno"] != DBNull.Value
                                ? long.Parse(sdr["Idno"].ToString())
                                : 0,
                        LastName = reader["Lname"] != DBNull.Value
                                    ? reader["Lname"].ToString()
                                    : ""
                        //rest of the fields
                     };
               return objGard;             
       }
   }
}
return null;
```

}

```
public Graduate GetInformation()
{
    return DAT.GetInformation(this.username);
}

var grad = GetInformation();
if(grad ==null) return;

txtId.Text = grad.Id;
txtLasName.Text = grad.LastName;
```

Comment: Should i put these in my presentation layer?

Comment: Shouldn't be! Ideally you should create a Class which represent the data (probably *Graduates*) in this case and create a class object based on data and return that to presentation layer

Comment: I am using 3 tier. How can I return it to let it populate the textboxes?

Comment: @humpty dumpty - what is the point of creating a class to represent the data - populating a 'Graduates' object and then using the object as a datasource? This really seems, to me, to be creating a class/object for the sake of it. Why not just use the SqlDataReader as the datasource?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse : I initially thought that, but OPs' requirement is not to fill the grid-view, populate some text boxes (read the OPs comment) !!

Comment: @Jm Santos - if you insist on a data access layer, a business layer and a presentation layer - do as humpty dumpty suggested. In your data access layer populate a sqldatareader and use it to populate an instance of your business object, then use the business object in the presentation layer to populate text boxes or gridviews or whatever you want to do with the data.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how can I populate the sqldatareader in my DAL class?

Comment: Ohh now I slightly understand how you did it.. But can you make a much easier codes to understand because I don't understand everything.

Comment: @JmSantos: Oh man, I can't do all work for you!! And this is not a code which hard to understand. if you unsure any specific ask me. I try to clarify!

Comment: I'm having a hard time how can I populate the sqldatareader like the way I used to. Like in doing an Insert statement in DAL like.. with parameters..

Comment: @JmSantos: Ok check now